# Any standard pattern or strategy for making Null Object Immutable

Tags: java, design-patterns

In java, we prefer `null object` pattern than cluttering the code with not null check in all referencing. Recently we faced a problem over using `null object` by keeping a `singleton` object. 
Assume we have `Person` class as below

```
public class Person {
 public String firstName;
 public String lastName;
 public boolean isNull() {
  return false;
 }
 public static final Person NULL = new Person() {
  public boolean isNull() { return true; }  
 }
}
```

In this case, though I have declared `NULL` object as final, I can still modify the member variable and its available globally.

```
Person nullRef = Person.NULL;
Person.NULL.firstName = "sample";
System.out.println(nullRef.firstName);
```

In this case, its just three fields and I could solve mutability problem by overriding those three getter methods. But pratically there will be many fields which will be tough to override all corresponding getter methods. 
Is there any standard pattern or strategy to solve this mutability issue in `NULL` objects?

Comment: Why not make the Person object immutable?

Comment: To be honest, this whole "null object pattern" doesn't strike me as all that great an idea (except in some limited circumstances).

Comment: @NPE I was actually wondering what a null person could be...

Comment: Definitely what NPE and assylias have said. If you want a "better" way of dealing with null, take a look at the google guava library's utility classes / methods: http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained

Comment: How about protecting the members, creating setters for them and testing for this.isNull() in the setters before doing anything?

Comment: @AlexandruMihai The problem is we are dealing with code which uses ORM. So assume there is an entity class for which the corresponding column member fields are auto-generated. It will be so vast to implement all those fields setter and getter I believe. I am looking for any AOP kind of solution.

Comment: @assylias Person need not be immutable since this is just a bean. Null Person is just to replace the snippet `person !=null && person.firstName != null` as `person.firstName != null`

Comment: @sundar: It's true, that solution doesn't quite work in an ORM situation. But seeing the purpose in your latest comment, couldn't you just replace your tests with !person.isNull() since that will keep returning true for the NULL object no matter what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Optional From Google Guava library

```
Optional<Integer> possible = Optional.of(5);
possible.isPresent(); // returns true
possible.get(); // returns 5
```

Quoting the library documentation:

> Besides the increase in readability that comes from giving null a
>   name, the biggest advantage of Optional is its idiot-proof-ness

This is more natural way of dealing with null objects

[Optional Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained)

Answer (score 1):

You need to have two levels of interface: One for the immutable part (only getters and immutable methods) and one for mutable parts that extends the immutable interface. Then the code needs to be refactored to only use the most restrictive interface possible in all relevant places.

So

```
public interface ImmutablePerson {
  final String getFirstName();
}

public interface MutablePerson extends ImmutablePerson {
  final void setLastName(final String newName);
}
```

Yes, now MutablePerson "is a" ImmutablePerson, but only when used as one :)

Additionally, the isNull check indicates that you need to think more about inversion of control.

To be concrete:

When you find yourself writing code like

```
if (!person.isNull()) {
  person.setLastName("Foo");
}
```

You should instead just use your Null Object and think of it as a neutral element insted. Like so:

First:

```
final Person NullPerson = new Person() {
  void setLastName(final String newName) {
    // Do nothing, this is a neutral (Null) object
  }
}
```

...and then later:

```
// Never need to check for isNull ever again - null objects just decide to ignore your request
person.setLastName("Foo");
```

Comment: Having `MutablePerson` extend `ImmutablePerson` in such way will result in violation of the Liskov Substitution Principle - not a good thing in OOP.

Answer (score 0):

- You need to make all the fields "private" so that these are not accessible outside except for the getter code.
- You need to modify "setter" methods and not the getter ones for making it immutable.
  For eg.

  public String setFirstName(String name){
  if(!isNull()){
  firstName = name;
  }
  }

Comment: The problem is we are dealing with code which uses ORM. So assume there is an entity class for which the corresponding column member fields are auto-generated. It will be so vast to implement all those fields setter and getter I believe. #copypaste